# Reaper pattern in Akka sends its Terminated message to dead letter box

Tags: scala, akka, lifecycle, scalatest

I've been trying the [reaper pattern](http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2) suggested by the Akka team. It does sound good in theory, but the provided unit test does not pass in either sbt or Eclipse's JUnit runner.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.actor._
import akka.testkit.{TestKit, ImplicitSender, TestProbe}
import org.scalatest.{WordSpec, BeforeAndAfterAll}
import org.scalatest.matchers.MustMatchers
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ReaperSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("ReaperSpec"))
    with ImplicitSender with WordSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll with MustMatchers
{
    import Reaper._

    override def afterAll() {
        system.shutdown()
    }

    // Our test reaper. Sends the snooper a message when all the souls have been reaped
    private class TestReaper(snooper: ActorRef) extends Reaper {
        def allSoulsReaped(): Unit = snooper ! "Dead"
    }

    "Reaper" should {
        "work" in {
            // Set up some dummy Actors
            val a = TestProbe()
            val b = TestProbe()
            val c = TestProbe()
            val d = TestProbe()
            // Build our reaper
            val reaper = system.actorOf(Props(new TestReaper(testActor)))
            // Watch a couple 
            reaper ! WatchMe(a.ref)
            reaper ! WatchMe(d.ref)
            // Stop them
            system.stop(a.ref)
            system.stop(d.ref)
            // Make sure we've been called
            within (1 seconds, 5 seconds) {
                expectMsg("Dead")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After adding logging to the actors, I noticed that the Terminated message ended up in the dead letter box. So the reaper actor never got the Terminated message.

```
[ERROR] [08/05/2014 11:10:27.244] [ReaperSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4]
    [akka://ReaperSpec/user/$a] Monitored actor [Actor[akka://ReaperSpec/system/testActor2#-1060476766]] terminated (akka.actor.DeathPactException)
[INFO] [08/05/2014 11:10:27.248] [ReaperSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2]
    [akka://ReaperSpec/user/$a] Message [akka.actor.Terminated] from Actor[akka://ReaperSpec/system/testActor5#2029818496] to Actor[akka://ReaperSpec/user/$a#1787786349] was not delivered.
    [1] dead letters encountered, no more dead letters will be logged. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I thought that `system.stop(watchedActorRef)` would guarantee delivery of a Terminated message to all the actors that are watching the `watchedActorRef`. What am I missing?

Comment: Strange, I modified your test a little bit (switching over to specs2 because that's what I use) and removed that 'within' block and everything worked immediately.  I also removed that system.shutdown.  Maybe that had something to do with it...

Comment: @cmbaxter I just tried disabling the system.shutdown on afterAll() and took out the `within` block. `expectMsg("Dead")` still dies within 3 seconds, because `Terminated` gets put into the dead letter queue and never reaches the Reaper.

Comment: @Alan - Works for me with Akka 2.3.9 with a slight modification.  I pasted your code and the Reaper code and ran it. The first time I ran it, I got an Assertion saying that the minimum time (1 seconds) in your within clause is too long (it only took 19ms to run). I changed the minimum time to 0 seconds and it ran fine.